# Is it possible to have a DataContract using a type from a library?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm setting up a WCF interface.  My data contract looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "wcf")]
[KnownType(typeof(TypeFromLibrary))]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public TypeFromLibrary myProp { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use `TypeFromLibrary` in a DataContract like this?  All of the examples I have seen only use int, string, double, etc as the property type.

NOTE: I have the copies of the library on both the server and client side of the WCF.

Comment: do you have any problems with this code? :o)

Comment: I'm having trouble sending `TypeFromLibrary` objects across the WCF.

Comment: show errors or what you have

Comment: You must ensure that wcf knows all types and they can be serialized. Thus, if your TypeFromLibrary class cannot be serialized, ensure that it has DataContract attribute, and if it has any complex type, they must be marked as DataContract too.

Comment: @RicardoPontual `TypeFromLibrary` is not serialized and I don't have access to its source code.  Is it possible to inherit it in another class and make that class serializable?

Comment: It's possible to inherit, but since each member must be marked as DataMember, you must override all properties. I think a better solution is to create a class that clones TypeFromLibrary, and set DataContrat/DataMember and use it in your contract instead original TypeFromLibrary.

Comment: Ok I am going to try this, but how do I handle any methods from TypeFromLibrary as far as DataContract/DataMember goes?

Comment: Nvm, had a brain lapse there.

Comment: @RicardoPontual what if TypeFromLibrary inherits other classes/interfaces that haven't been decorated with DataContract/DataMember?  Do I have to do the same to each of those as well?

Comment: Since .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and above, you don't need to decorate all members with DataContract, but or you decorate DataContract to all members or neither of them, if you mark any property, you must mark all, thus verify your framework version and if your class has all or none of your attributes marked as DataMember.
The only issue I had was about enums, so I usually decorate all members to avoid any problems.

Comment: @RicardoPontual just wanted to let you know, this worked, but the nest of inherited custom objects runs so deep that I'm going to look into some alternative solutions. Thanks for your time!  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Josh good, any doubt just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post what worked for me in case someone else was having trouble.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "wcf", IsReference = true)]
public class NewType : TypeFromLibrary
{
    public NewType(TypeFromLibrary baseObj)
    {
        //set all props here
    }

    public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomeEvent;

    [OperationContract]
    public string SomeBaseFunction()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public CustomBaseProp SomeProp { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int SomeInt { get; set;}
}
```

This worked as long as `SomeProp` was null.  As soon as a value was given to `SomeProp` the same error showed up.  I went to the next level and decorated `CustomBaseProp` as well and that worked.  However, I stopped there because there are more custom classes in `CustomBaseProp` and wanted to seek alternative solutions.  To fix completely fix it, you would have to decorate the  `CustomBaseProp` class and other custom classes with the appropriate attributes.